# Is there a way to provide for an exception to a NOT EXISTS clause?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a query (that works) with a NOT EXISTS statement that all the names returned cannot be an internal employee. However, I have a record with an external person that has the same name as an internal employee. This record is being excluded but I need it.

I have no clue how to write an exception to my NOT EXISTS to pull in this person.

Sample code:

```
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from dbo.EmployeeTable e
INNER JOIN dbo.ResourceTable r on e.empID = r.employeeID
WHERE r.TypeID = 2 --this is internal employees
AND e.EmployeeName = x.UserName --this user name comes from a join earlier on in my code.)
```

I need to somehow add code to say "except when x.UserName = [John Doe]"

Can someone out there please help me?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: add an OR to your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a check based on id, not `EmployeeName`. Something like:

```
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from dbo.ResourceTable r 
               WHERE r.TypeID = 2 --this is internal employees
                 AND r.employeeID = x.UserId 
              )
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was a great idea.  However, the table that I'm pulling the names from does not contain employee IDs.  I know!  Bad design.  I had to pull in a special table to compare the names to and that worked.  Luckily it didn't slow my stored procedure down much at all.  Thanks again!!